# Given $2$ graphs $G_{1},G_{2}$ whose degrees are equal to $100$, prove that we can use finitely many operations on $G_{1}$ to tranform it to $G_{2}$

Tags: graph-theory

The operation on a graph is defined as follows: we take $4$ of its vertices $a,b,c,d$ such that the graph contains edges $\left\{ a,b \right\},\left\{ c,d \right\}$ but not edges $\left\{ a,c \right\},\left\{ b,d \right\}$. The operation deletes the existing edges and constructs the latter pair.

The two graphs need to have an equal number of vertices for the statement to be true.

I am fairly new to graph theory and this one interesting problem that is one of the first of the "more advanced" I encountered - i.e. deals with fairly large graphs. I am not entirely sure how advanced exactly this problem is, but its definitely different than the introductory level exercises I saw. What kind of approach should be taken in problems like these? I'd love to see some new interesting techniques.

Thank you

Comment: I know what is the degree of a vertex, but not what is the degree of a graph. What does that even mean?

Comment: Induction on the number of vertices? Perhaps you can work out how to get all the connections to one vertex correct, and then ignore it and work on the remaining vertices by induction.

Comment: @TomKern You seem to have an idea of what is being asked here. I, for one, do not. Please share your understanding.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Every vertex in the graph has degree 100

Comment: @texiwi Then the statement is not true, unless both graphs have equally many vertices.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yes, both graphs should have an equal amount of vertices, if all the vertices of both of them have degree 100. I will clarify that in the original post, thank you.

Comment: The operation needs clarification too. You say that a quadruple must contain {a,b}, {c,d} and not {a,c}, {b,d}; now what about {a,d} and {b,c}? Should they be absent, or that's irrelevant? In the latter case, do they get deleted in the operation as well?

Comment: They would indeed be irrelevant to the operation. The task described it as a square with two of its opposite edges missing, being transformed into the "opposite deficient" square, the diagonals do not play a role.